# D3 selection based on text, but needing sibling element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I'm struggling with a very specific need, I think. I'm drawing a tree structure, using this node config:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(160.65,400)">
   <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255,255,255);"></circle>
   <text y="18" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle" style="fill-opacity: 1;">data</text>
</g>
```

What I want to do is to select a circle based on the data from the text tag.

I've been reading about subselectors and filters in D3, but I'm new to it and don't quite get it. any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 option to select the text tag.

1. select by parent node class:

   ```
   var textTag = d3.select(".node text").text();
   if (textTag == "data") {
       var circleTag = d3.select(".node circle");
       console.log(circleTag);
   } else {
       console.log("Not find");
   }
   ```
2. select by tag:

   ```
    var textTag = d3.select("text").text();
    if (textTag == "data") {
       var circleTag = d3.select("circle");
       console.log(circleTag);
   } else {
       console.log("Not find");
   }
   ```

   Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/pz0x4ayp/1/).

Comment: Perfect! so simple, it just shows I need more practice with JS and D3.   Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) blog could help you to learn more about selection method in D3js.